# Cannot get .attr('aria-controls') using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

The problem is that jQuery returns `undefined` and I have no clue why...

The following runs with latest WordPress and Woocommerce. jQuery used is the WP default.

I have the following html (just a fragment for readability) and the button is hidden at first and revealed later.

Much below and activated by the user click on the "click me" button above to activate the following js:

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).on('click', '#llwoo-update-profile-field-button', function() {

    // $('#llwoo-update-profile-field-button').live('click', function() {
    let t = $('.ll-li-tabs .ui-state-active'); // returns OK
    console.log("Handler for .click() called. t=", t);
    let t2 = $('.ll-li-tabs .ui-state-active').attr('aria-controls'); // return undefined!
    console.log("Handler for .click() called. t2=", t2);
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="ll-li-tabs ui-tabs-tab ui-corner-top ui-state-default ui-tab ui-tabs-active ui-state-active" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tabs-2" aria-labelledby="ui-id-2" aria-selected="true" aria-expanded="true">
    <a href="#tabs-2" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" class="ui-tabs-anchor" id="ui-id-2">
      <div id="ll-box-TR" class="ll-box-s ll-box-TR">li with aria-controls</div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="llwoo-update-profile-field" class="llwoo-update-profile-field">
  <button id="llwoo-update-profile-field-button" type="button">click me</button></div>
```

`t`  has a value while `t2` is undefined and 'aria-controls' exists.

Any idea where the problem is? What am I missing?

EDIT: I replace `live` with `on` - Same problem remains...

Thanks!

Comment: `live` has been deprecated for a long while, what version of jQuery are you using? Please also create a [mre]. The easiest way of doing so would be to use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon looks like `<>` in the editor toolbar).

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks! I am using latest jQuery that comes with latest WordPress. I needed ```live``` because the button is hidden at first and revealed later. I there a better option than live?

Comment: _“I[s] there a better option than live? ”_ - that is stuff you can easily go and find out yourself, by reading the documentation for `.live()` - https://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: _“following html (just a fragment for readability)”_ - if you reduce stuff _too_ much, that is not helpful either. Please provide a _proper_ [mre] of the issue.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks! replaced ```live``` with ```on``` - Same behaviour still

Comment: That was actually the least important part of my comment. I was asking for a reproducible example, much like what was given in the answer you've received.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I wish I could reproduce... Too much code. I hope I can find some way. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to match div that contains just both classes you shouldn't add space between them in jquery selector

```
$('.ll-li-tabs .ui-state-active')
```

must be

```
$('.ll-li-tabs.ui-state-active')
```

i prefer to use id rather than class for something like this to avoid the problems or use class used one time and put it to selector without any other class.

Comment: YOU MADE MY DAY - the space did the trick!!! I would never expect that!!

Answer (score 4):

jquery doesn’t support `live()`. Use `on()`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#llwoo-update-profile-field-button').on('click', function() {
            let t = $('.ll-li-tabs');
            console.log( "Handler for .click() called. t=", t );
            let t2 = $('.ll-li-tabs').attr('aria-controls');
            console.log( "Handler for .click() called. t2=", t2 );
        }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="ll-li-tabs ui-tabs-tab ui-corner-top ui-state-default ui-tab ui-tabs-active ui-state-active" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tabs-2" aria-labelledby="ui-id-2" aria-selected="true" aria-expanded="true">
<a href="#tabs-2" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" class="ui-tabs-anchor" id="ui-id-2"><div id="ll-box-TR" class="ll-box-s ll-box-TR"></div></a>
</li>
<div id="llwoo-update-profile-field" class="llwoo-update-profile-field">
   <button id="llwoo-update-profile-field-button" type="button">click me</button></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I replaced live with on: ```        $(document).on('click', '#llwoo-update-profile-field-button', function() {
```
Still same issue

Comment: as well - you have not connected the jquery plugin, and there is no button `#llwoo-update-profile-field-button` - i fixed all this in my example. Now I’ll deal further with your problem.

Comment: Please note that the button exists and it activates the script properly. The code is inside latest WordPress with jQuery provided by default

Comment: Please check my example. I fixed now.

Comment: I tried your code - ```  $('#llwoo-update-profile-field-button').on('click', function() {``` Not working in my case. See my revised question above for click event that does work.

I guess I was misleading for not adding WordPress & Woocommerce - SORRY for being unclear.

The problem is still there.

Comment: But in my solution, you get the attribute name in the console.

Comment: @Mulli You can help everyone by following my advice and editing your question with a Stack Snippet -- you can see how it helps this answer by providing something that can be run here on Stack Overflow. If the example is not demonstrating the problem, edit it until it does.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you are getting multiple `objects` for `$('.ll-li-tabs .ui-state-active')`. And `attr` will select first of them and return the value.

Please note that you are having `ll-li-tabs` & `ui-state-active` both classes on `li` so you should be using them without   like `$('.ll-li-tabs.ui-state-active')`.

If you want to get `$('.ll-li-tabs.ui-state-active')` with specific `attribute` you can use [`attribute selector` `[]`](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/). In your case you can use like below.

`$('.ll-li-tabs.ui-state-active[aria-controls]')`

In below example I've set first `li` without `aria-controls` `attribute` and second `li` with `aria-controls`. Please check result for `$('.ll-li-tabs.ui-state-active').attr('aria-controls');` & `$('.ll-li-tabs.ui-state-active[aria-controls]').attr('aria-controls');`

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).on('click', '#llwoo-update-profile-field-button', function() {

    // $('#llwoo-update-profile-field-button').live('click', function() {
    let t = $('.ll-li-tabs.ui-state-active').attr('aria-controls'); // return undefined!
    console.log("Handler for .click() called. t=", t);
    let t2 = $('.ll-li-tabs.ui-state-active[aria-controls]').attr('aria-controls'); // return tabs-2!
    console.log("Handler for .click() called. t2=", t2);
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="ll-li-tabs ui-tabs-tab ui-corner-top ui-state-default ui-tab ui-tabs-active ui-state-active" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="ui-id-2" aria-selected="true" aria-expanded="true">
    <a href="#tabs-2" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" class="ui-tabs-anchor" id="ui-id-2">
      <div id="ll-box-TR" class="ll-box-s ll-box-TR">li 1 without aria-controls</div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="ll-li-tabs ui-tabs-tab ui-corner-top ui-state-default ui-tab ui-tabs-active ui-state-active" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tabs-2" aria-labelledby="ui-id-2" aria-selected="true" aria-expanded="true">
    <a href="#tabs-2" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" class="ui-tabs-anchor" id="ui-id-2">
      <div id="ll-box-TR" class="ll-box-s ll-box-TR">li 2 with aria-controls</div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="llwoo-update-profile-field" class="llwoo-update-profile-field">
<button id="llwoo-update-profile-field-button" type="button">click me</button></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You got it right - I wish I could mark your answer as well. The one above  was little earlier... Sorry. and THANKS!!! Much appreciated!